# Read/Write PLC tags folder from PLC using c#

Tags: c#, plc, tia-portal

I'm developing a C# application and I need to read/write values from PLC tags folder (TIA Portal).
I have looked at S7.Net library and Libnodave but they only read/write data blocks and not tags like my project.

What it proposes :

```cs
bool val = true;
plc.Write("DB1.DBX0.0", val);
```

What I'm willing to get :

```cs
bool val = true;
plc.Write("I0.0", val);
```

Do you have any idea of doing it ?
PS: I know there is a old post like this but not resolved.

Comment: you can write in a DB and after coping the outputs internally, i have no experience with `S7.NET` but i know that with `Snap7` is possible https://sourceforge.net/p/snap7/discussion/general/thread/a99ad9f5/

Comment: Thanks, the thing is that I don't want to use DBs because my TIA project is training lesson (can't be modified)

Comment: i would suggest to use the address as proposed in the link that i sent you, maybe it will work

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not a C# library

Comment: There is a c# library  https://github.com/fbarresi/Sharp7

Answer (score 0):

I'd recomend to use [Sharp7](https://snap7.sourceforge.net/), it is a C# port of Snap7 library. To *read/write* input *bytes* you can use **EBRead**/**EBWrite** functions or if you want to *read/write* *bit* use **ReadArea**/**WriteArea** functions [Sharp7 wiki](https://github.com/fbarresi/Sharp7/wiki/IO-functions). Also check [target compability](https://snap7.sourceforge.net/snap7_client.html#target_compatibility) for your plc model.

For example to read plc input code can look like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new S7Client();
        //I connect to PLCSIM via NetToPLCSim
        int result = client.ConnectTo("127.0.0.1", 0, 2);
        if (result != 0)
        {
            //If value result of operation != 0 shows error
            Console.WriteLine(client.ErrorText(result));
        }
        else
        {
            //Buffer it is a byte array of some size, that you use to read data from plc or to write to it
            //This buffer size is 1 byte, bc i need only one bit and EBRead can't read less than 1 byte
            var buffer = new byte[1];
            //First parameter is offset, i.e. if you read 1 byte from offset 0 you read whole IB0
            //Second parameter define how many bytes you will read in buffer, make it equal to your buffer size
            //Third parameter is buffer in which the data is written when you perform read operation
            result = client.EBRead(0, buffer.Length, buffer);
            if (result != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(client.ErrorText(result));
            }
            else
            {
                //Here you convert data from buffer to desiered c# type
                //First parameter is buffer with data
                //Second parameter is byte offset in buffer 
                byte input = S7.GetByteAt(buffer, 0);
                //Third parameter is only to get bit operation, to specify bit number in byte
                bool I0_0 = S7.GetBitAt(buffer, 0, 0);
                Console.WriteLine(I0_0);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

[NetToPLCSim](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nettoplcsim/)

Comment: I don't understand what are the parameters of the function :

`public int EBRead(int Start, int Size, byte[] Buffer)`
Imagine that I want to Read the input %I0.0
I have to write this ?
`plc.EBRead(0,1,0)`

Comment: @PaulMaubray, i added example of code

Comment: @PaulMaubray does it hepleped or no?